# Looking for a good jQuery table with Pagination, Multi-column sorting, and row selection

Tags: jquery, sorting, pagination, tablesorter

I've used the table from dataTables.net before and it worked pretty good.  However, it does not provide row selection.  I've found tables that did at most two of these at a time, but not all three.  I'm still pretty novice at JavaScript and at the time don't want to dive into someone else's code to add the missing feature.  I wanted to see if there is already a table out there that does all three functions I need.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Does row selection need to persist across pages, like gmail for example?

Comment: That would be awesome, but no, it does not.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTable row selection examples from their site:

[Single Row](http://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html)

[Multiple Rows with Page memory](http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html)

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look into this.  I'd hate to have to write the function to JSON the data again, but it might be well worth it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/). It's free, it has **very good** [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs), excellent [working examples](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) where you can see all the features in action. It has all functions you want and many more.

Answer (score 0):

I think Sencha's EXT js will give you everything you're looking for but it's not free. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/grid/multiple-sorting.html